# Apache reverse rewrite

Tags: rewrite, apache-2.4

Is it possible to make the URL `index.php?view=something` back into `/something`?

Comment: Yes. The rewrite rules can manipulate any data it's given. You can't recover data lost in a previous rewrite (usually).

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [&?]view=([^&]*)
RewriteRule index.php$ /%1
```

Note that, if you're not careful, a crafty attacker might be able to abuse this; for example, by generating arbitrary URIs by passing parameters to "view".  Appropriate precautions should be taken.

Also, you might want to append an [L], [R], or [R=301] to the RewriteRule (or a combination thereof), depending on your exact intent.

Comment: As long as the URL is rewritten to the same server, how can this technique be abused? (curious because this is how I do it on my website).

Comment: One example off the top of my head: let's say you wanted to let rewritten index.php's be deeper than "/", so you had a rule like `RewriteRule index.php$ %1 [L,R]`.  Imagine if I gave you the URI
`http://www.yoursite.com/dir/index.php?view=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.evilattackersite.com`—what happens?

Comment: haha the views are already set.